# Simplify ignores DiracDelta contribution from Coulomb sources

Tags: vector-calculus

Executing the following line,

```
Simplify[Div[Grad[-1/Sqrt[{x, y, z}.{x, y, z}], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}]]
```

yields 0. However, this is incorrect, since $\nabla\cdot\nabla\left(|\mathbf{r}|^{-1}\right)=-4\pi\delta(\mathbf{r})$ in 3-space.

I understand that this problem is coming from the fact that `Simplify` assumes $\mathbf{r}\neq\mathbf{0}$. However, I don't know how to coax Mathematica into giving the correct result without essentially having to resort to doing mathematics by hand, which kind of defeats the purpose of using a computer algebra system. In this case the result is obviously wrong so no harm is done, but for more complicated vector expressions I have no idea whether `Simplify` is going to give wrong answers without warning when applied to functions with spatial singularities.

Is there any automated way to handle such singularities to give correct answers in Mathematica?

Comment: See if you can make progress with `Laplacian[-1/EuclideanDistance[{x, y, z}, {0, 0, 0}], {x, y, z}]`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way, which certainly doesn't handle all singularities. First we gather the denominator of every subexpression.

```
allDens[expr_] := Union[Cases[expr, e_ :> Denominator[e], {0, Infinity}]]
```

From here, we'll just throw a warning that each denominator is assumed to be nonzero.

```
acknowledgeSingularitiesSimplify[expr_] := Module[{dens},
  dens = Thread[allDens[expr] == 0];
  dens = Cases[Union[Simplify[dens]], _Equal];

  ConditionalExpression[Simplify[expr], Reduce[Not[Or @@ dens]]]
]

acknowledgeSingularitiesSimplify[
  Div[Grad[-1/Sqrt[{x, y, z}.{x, y, z}], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}]]

(* ConditionalExpression[0, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2] != 0] *)
```

Another thing you might look into, to fully be integrated with `Simplify`, is the option `TransformationFunction`.